# Query Exchange server using DirectoryServices

Tags: exchange-server, directoryservices, ldap-query

the question just came to me from a different team. The question was "how to query the users in the exchange server's particular User group". Its said that the Exchange server user group is not linked to an Ad group. The examples i could get are all for querying based on AD group. I heard there are two ways either through SQL or through DirectoryServices. Either solution is fine, but through DirectoryServices will be super awesome! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the group is an Active Directory Group, you can use System.DirectoryServices. However, if it's a distribution group in an Exchange public/private folder, you neeed to access Exchange directly. The API suited for the latter depends on your Exchange Server version. With Exchange 2003, use WebDAV, although distribution list expansion is quite complicated, but I could give you some sample code. With Exchange 2007 and later, use EWS or the Exchange Managed API, if you are using .Net.